# Where does the NULL in function output come from?

Tags: r, function

Below I create a data frame called `c_data`.  Note that the variable `ri` has one missing value.

Then I write a function that checks data. One step is to stop the function if `ri` has missing data.  (I removed from the function the syntax not of relevance to my question).

I provide output.

The function performs as expected, except it prints `NULL` in addition to the expected outcome.  Why does it print `NULL`?

```
#create data to test function
r <- c(.15, .10, NA)
N <- c(100, 86, 56)
chrvar <- c("a", "b", "c")
c_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(r,N, chrvar))
#change variable type from factor to numeric
c_data$r <- as.numeric(c_data$r)
#change N variable type from factor to integer
c_data$N <- as.integer(c_data$N)
#change chrvar from factor to character
c_data$chrvar <- as.character(c_data$chrvar)
str(c_data)


myFun <- function(ri= ri, ni=ni, data = data)
 {

  #add ri and ni to the data frame named data
  data$ri <- ri
  data$ni <- ni

  #does ri have any missing data
  num.missing.ri <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(data))
     {
       if (is.na(data$ri[i] == TRUE)) num.missing.ri = num.missing.ri + 1
     }
  if(num.missing.ri != 0)
     {
     print(cat("Number of missing values in ri is", num.missing.ri,"\n"))
     stop("ri has missing data. myFun is terminated.") 
     }

 }

      myFun(ri = r, ni = N, data = c_data)
```

This produces this output:

```
myFun(ri = r, ni = N, data = c_data)

##Number of missing values in ri is 1 
##NULL
## Error in myFun(ri = r, ni = N, data = c_data) : 
##  ri has missing data. myFun is terminated.
```

Why does it print NULL?

Comment: Just FYI, you can obtain number of missing values in a column with `sum(is.na(data$column))`

Comment: It may be because your function is not actually returning any values, its just telling R to print under that condition. Possibly try implementing the `return` command when defining the function?

Comment: couple things: first I noticed (is.na(data$ri[i] == TRUE)) is checking if the value is true THEN checking if its NA. Your brackets are not matched up. Second what you are doing, as mentioned before me, can be done in one line.

Answer (score 4):

`NULL` is printed as this is the return value of `cat` function. 
You don't need `print` and `cat`.

```
x <- cat("asdf")
x
##NULL
print(x)
##NULL
```

In your case `cat` prints the information regarding missing values and then `print` prints the value returned by `cat`, which is `NULL`

FYI: You can make this more efficient, for example:

```
if(any(ind.na <- is.na(c_data$ri))) stop(paste("ri has", sum(ind.na), "missing values"))
```

Comment: Alternatively, just use `paste` instead of `cat` and you won't see the NULL print out.

Comment: Thank you for your help> I very much appreciate it.

Comment: @user2502904 you welcome, don't forget to accept answers that helped you (also in previous questions you asked)

Answer (score 1):

@adibender answered this correctly.

Just do this:

```
cat("Number of missing values in ri is", num.missing.ri,"\n")
```

Or this:

```
print(paste("Number of missing values in ri is", num.missing.ri))
```

---

Also, I just wanted to make a note since you are new to functions. When you write your function `myFun`, you are setting default cases for your variables.

So when you instantiate your function as `function(ri = ri, ni = ni, data = data)`, you're telling R that in the case where the user left out ri, ni, and/or data from their function call, use ri, ni, and/or data instead. This doesn't really make sense for the function unless you have instantiated ri, ni, or data elsewhere.

Instead, you can just write the function as `function(ri, ni, data)` and R will throw an error if the use leaves these arguments out.